# How to get Automation connected to a Journey API response?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I just want to ask what Id should I use or key value pair that I need to use to get the connected automation from my journey?

I am using this endpoint `.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions/{journeyid}`

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for you to get your journeyid with this. It will return a list of all your journeys including id.

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
GET /interaction/v1/interactions
Content-Type: application/json
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getInteractionCollection.html